# Adding Product Category hierarchy to a Sales Fact Aggregation

Tags: powerbi, aggregation

I have a fairly standard Sales fact table (ProductKey, DateKey, StoreKey, Quantity), and then I have a product dimension, DimProduct (ProductKey, Category, Division, Department, Group, Subgroup, ProductDescription, ProductCode).

In my report, I have a matrix with a half dozen simple measures, mostly SUM('Fact'[Column]) or maybe CALCULATE(SUM('Fact'[Column]),FILTER('Fact'[Column]>0)), but that's as complex as it gets. I have a couple of hierchical slicers to filter for specific stores/divisions.

And I have Product Category hierarchy on one axis of my matrix and 10 simple measures in Values.

I'm trying to speed it up by filtering the Category hierarchy better, but I can't create Aggregations on a dimension table. Do I have to put at least some of the category hierarchy back into the fact table to do this? (Seems just completely backwards, but I can't figure any other way to do it.) I'm looking at the documentation on the Microsoft site for Aggregations (here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/aggregations-advanced), and the ProductSubcategoryKey is the closest to what I'm trying to do, but I wanted to group by more columns in the Product dimension, but I can't even select them.

(Sorry, I'm brand new to Aggregations, so I'm a bit lost).

Any idea how to fix my matrix so that it loads faster? I thought I could use Aggregations to do it, but I basically need to aggregate on the dimension table. I could do something hideous and merge some of the Product hierarchy back to the fact table, but that seems just so wrong. Feel free to send me to a blog or anything that explains it. I just need to figure out how to get this thing to work faster!

Answer (score 1):

This example from the doc should be directly applicable to your scenario:

[image]

Only where Sales Agg has Product Subcategory, you would have create a snowflake Product Category table that has one row per Product Category, and a 1-Many relationship with Product.

Alternatively you can create your Agg table with ProductKey instead, so each Product Category would need to aggregate the individual Products in the category.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding - so split the hierarchy into separate related tables? (Seems completely counterintuitive, that's all). So basically work my way up the chain from the lowest level of the hierarchy to the highest level?
So maybe Group-->Department-->Division-->Category?

Would it make any difference if I were to basically (if I can) redirect the PQ that parses stuff in blob storage and into the model into a SQL database and use that as the source of my reporting? I think right now there's no database to send the aggregation stuff back to. Would that make any difference?

Comment: Aggregations are not available in Import models.  You can build summary tables in import mode, but you have to reference them directly in your measures and visuals.

Comment: Okay, that's huge. I was wondering why it wouldn't let me create aggregations. (everything was grayed out). If I were to use DirectQuery against a Data Warehouse, it would work though, right? (Well, that's what Phil Seamark's article implied: https://dax.tips/2021/09/06/intro-to-power-bi-aggregations/ )

Comment: Would it make any difference if I were to persist the PowerQuery results into tables in (say) a data warehouse? Or start with summary tables?

Comment: Using summary tables as your Fact table is a great way to improve performance.

Comment: Would I create a summary table for each level of my Product dimension hierarchy? is there a good article on it somewhere?

Comment: Generally you build the summary at the lowest grain that your common visuals need.  Eg (Product, Day, Geography).  Build the "front page" of your report using this table, and only use the details table for other pages that are less used.

Comment: Would it improve things if I were to import the CSV files into a table in a database on Azure, and then created a proper data model there and created a composite model? (Or is that a $$$$ thing?)